# How to find maximum data point in a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a method to read all the numerical values available in a excel sheet and find the largest/Maximum one?

From a 50 by 50 data set, I am trying to find the maximum data point. So basically, a function which can analyze the whole excel file regardless of columns and rows.

I wrote a function which was to find the maximum of each column and then again find the Maximum between them.

But I am looking for a more efficient way. I will be working with very large file.

Thanks

Comment: `df.max().max() ` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.read_csv('.../data.csv').select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).max().max()
```

Returns the maximum numeric value across the whole data frame.

Answer (score 0):

The below will work. Check comments for more detail. Pandas is a great library to handle this.

```
import pandas as pd

# file_path should be the full path of wherever your csv file is located
# this loads the csv into a pandas data frame
# a convenient table-like data structure
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# get the max values in every column 
column_maxes_series = df.max()

# get the max value of the Series
overall_max = column_maxes_series.max()
```

Check your data to make sure it is all numbers. It will process with strings, but it would be probably strange for whatever analysis you are doing. Also, obviously pd.read_csv() will only work with csv files.